# How do I remove a class from the entire document

Tags: jquery

I tried `$(document).removeClass("myClassname")` but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
$(".myClassname").removeClass("myClassname")
```

`$(".myClassname")` will match all elements that have the class `myClassname`.

Comment: i tried. dint know there was some 10 minute rule for accepting answer !

Comment: not 10, meta.stackoverflow mentions that there is a 15 minute rule

Answer (score 9):

I think you are looking for this. It will select all the elements with class `myClassname` and remove that class for those elements.

```
$('.myClassname').removeClass('myClassname');
```